# adr not working in thumb2?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am using an arduino due board. I wrote the following piece of code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

extern "C" unsigned int asm_add ();

extern "C" volatile unsigned int x;
extern "C" volatile unsigned int y;
extern "C" volatile unsigned int z;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("exiting setup");
}
void loop()
{
    Serial.print("x - ");
    Serial.println(x);
    Serial.print("y - ");
    Serial.println(y);
    Serial.print("z before add is - ");
    Serial.println(z);

    Serial.println("calling asm_add");
    z = asm_add();
    Serial.print("asm_add addition result is - ");
    Serial.println(z);
    Serial.println("exiting loop");
    delay(3000);
    z=500;
}
```

And here's the assembly part:

```
.syntax unified
.section .text
.thumb
.thumb_func
.cpu cortex-m3
.align 2

.type asm_add2 STT_FUNC
.global asm_add
.global x
.global y
.global z

asm_add:

    ldr r0, =x
    //adr r0, x
    ldr r0, [r0]
    ldr r1, =y
    ldr r1, [r1]

    add r0, r1
    ldr r1, =z
    str r0, [r1]
    bx lr

.section .data
.align 2
x:
    .word 0x10
y:
    .word 0x20
z:
    .word 0x100
```

When I use the  ldr statement in the asm function, I get this output -

```
x - 16
y - 32
z before asm_add
asm_add addition result is - 48
exiting loop
```

But when I changed the address loading in asm_add to use adr instead of ldr (the one thats commented, not all three ldrs),  I get this output. So why the adr statement does not work.

```
exiting setup
x - 16
y - 32
z before add is - 256
calling asm_add
asm_add addition result is - 324303
exiting loop
```

Comment: Did you [look at the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html)?  Try to use `adrl`.  You may also use *sub-sections* to put a read/write segment in the data table.  Or convert your assembler to **leave** the address of `x` and use load with offset.  Ie, `ldr r2,=x\n ldr r0, [r2]\nldr r1, [r2,#4]\nadd r0,r1\nstr r0, [r2,#8]`.  `adr` is not the tool you need.  It is usually used to setup a non-continuous return address with a `b`ranch; instead of `bl`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ARM documentation on "arm.com" the "adr" instruction has some limitations.

One of the limitations is that "adr" can only be used for addresses in a certain distance to the "adr" instruction. This also means that it is not possible to use "adr" for addresses in another section (the "x" symbol is in the ".data" section while the "adr" instruction is in the ".code" section).

However this documentation is about the "official" behaviour while GNU assembler often behaves differently than the official behaviour so I tested the behaviour of GNU assembler:

- One of the two versions of the GNU assembler I tested always printed an error message when I tried to use "adr" to access an address in a different section
- The other version printed an error message in Thumb code but it generated buggy code (without any warning message) in ARM (non-Thumb) code
- Obviously the version that comes with the Arduino toolkit generates buggy code for Thumb code without a warning message, too.

Comment: That makes adr useless, it probably can only be used for reading constants in the text section.

Comment: For modern programs you are right. The "adr" pseudo-instruction has been introduced with the first ARM CPUs in 1987. In that times assemblers did not distinguish between .text and .data sections. As far as I know smaller ARM-based microcontrollers do not have memory protection so you can miss-use the .text section to store data... However this would not work on a Raspberry Pi (which has memory protection mechanisms).

Comment: on due (cortex-m3), the data is sram while the text is flash. any gains by using adr instead of ldr will be made useless by delaying instruction fetch. I also searched gcc generated assembler files for my sources, no where i found that its using adr.

Comment: You are right. Missusing the .text section for data is only possible with code in RAM, not in Flash. The official ARM manual says that the "LDR Rn,=value" pseudo-instruction will be automatically replaced by the fastest and least memory consuming instruction(s) that will load the value into Rn. This means that "ldr Rn,=value" will automatically be replaced by the most efficient instruction available and you cannot have any gain when using another instruction instead.

Comment: Well, I dont know how true that is. All of mine are getting replaced by something like this - ldr reg, [pc, #208]...so it pc relative addressing, its probably using a table of addresses, which cant possibly be the best option, two memory hits for one.

Comment: `adr` is not a **REAL** instruction.  It will translate to `ldr rX, [PC, #offset]`.  You can not 'scan generated assembler' for the instruction.

Comment: @artlessnoise GCC translates `adr rX, addr` to `add rX, pc, #offset`. This is the reason why the destination address must be in the same section; in the case of `ldr rX, [pc, #offset]` the assembler can store the address `addr` at the end of the code and simply load it using `ldr`. Therefore the address can be in the full 4GiB address range.

Comment: Right, but the point is `adr` will never exist as it is a pseudo-op.  The OP said they could not file the `adr` instruction.  *I also searched gcc generated assembler...*.  My comment was just meant to say this fruitless.  The compiler will use both  `ldr rX, [PC, #offset]` and `add rX, PC, #offset`.  I mis-remembers `ldr rX, =value` translation.  Thank you.